# Vue.js data value wont change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

i have a data named: `cat_pressed`

also have this function to change the data value :

```
changeCat(){
            this.cat_pressed === 'brauh'
}
```

but whenever i call the function the value won't change don't know why I've tried everything but nothing worked with me.

Comment: Are you trying to assign to `cat_pressed`? In that case, you want `=` rather than `===` (which is used for checking equality)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you've accidentally used the wrong operator.

[===](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) is used for checking equality - but you want to assign the the value to `cat_pressed`, so you're after [=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment).

```
changeCat(){
    this.cat_pressed = 'brauh'
}
```